# Question on integration notation

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

This is a question regarding a statement on page 7 of the lecture notes https://vittoriasilvestri.files.wordpress.com/2021/11/lecture_notes_2017.pdf.

Let $a:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be cadlag (right-continuous with left limits) and non-decreasing, with $a(0)=0$. Then there exists a unique Borel measure $da$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that for all $s<t$ we have $$da((s,t]) = a(t)-a(s).$$

Then, for any measurable and integrable $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, we can define the (Lebesgue-Stieltjes) integral $$(f\cdot a)(t)=\int_{(0,t]}f(s)da(s).$$

The author then mentions that if $a$ is continuous then $f\cdot a$ is continous and we can unambiguously write $$\int_{(0,t]}f(s)da(s) = \int_0^tf(s)da(s).$$

I'm relatively new to measure-theoretic integrals and so I am unsure as to how the integral on the RHS above has been defined, and why it requires continuity for the identity to be true. Additionally, is the RHS integral defined in the case of non-continuity of the LHS, and it is just that the equality does not hold? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We always integrate functions with respect to a given measure, over a given set. The notation $\int_0^t$ suppresses the notation for the set. Should it be  $(0,t), [0,t), (0,t]$ or $[0,t]$? This becomes important if singletons have positive measure (for example the Dirac measure $\delta_0$ has $\delta_0(\{0\})=1$ by definition). So, for the notation $\int_0^t$ to be unambiguous, we need singletons to have zero measure.

Comment: Ah okay, so am I right in concluding that in this case $da(\{t\}) = a(t)-a(t^-)$, where $a(t^-)=\lim_{s\to t^-}a(s)$, which is not necessarily $0$, leading to ambiguity? Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, look at a sequence of intervals $(s_n,t]$, where $s_1<s_2<\cdots<t$ and $s_n\to t$. Then, by continuity of measure, $da(\{t\})=da\left(\bigcap(s_n,t]\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}da((s_n,t])=a(t)-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a(s_n)$, and since $a$ has left-limits, this is equal to $da(\{t\})=a(t)-\lim\limits_{s\to t^-}a(s)$.